# Is it somehow possible to remove competitors road in openttd?

Tags: openttd

It is really annoying that I can not restructure a city because human competitor in multiplayer mode put his road inside. Is it any option to disable remove others road?

Comment: Public (as in, owned by the city) roads can be destroyed at will but it is highly expensive to do so and the city usually prevents building more roads from happening. Private roads can't be destroyed AFAIK. If it was possible to destroy other people's property, people would interfere with each other in a never-ending process or until someone runs out of money. Could you describe your concrete situation?

Comment: I wanted to build a channel for boat to build harbour near my train station, but there was a piece of road inbetween build by a competitor.

Comment: How about you build a system of locks and [Aqueducts](https://wiki.openttd.org/Waterway_construction#Building_Aqueducts)?

Comment: You could try asking/paying the competitor to remove it?

Comment: I have done it and he was helpfull, but I do not like to wait for it.

Comment: It's possible to build a rail track on the oad and stop a train on the road. That effectively blocks the road. It doesn't remove the road, but at least it stops them from using it.

Answer (score 5):

In a multiplayer game against human components, there is no legitimate way for you to remove another player's tiles as a different company.

Depending on your morals, there is however another way. In multiplayer, multiple people can control one company and during a game you can switch which company you are playing for. Provided that the company whose tiles you wish to remove does not have a password set, you can join their company, remove the tiles which are in your way and then rejoin your own company.

Of course, the players for the company whose tiles you removed will likely be angry and you'll probably find yourself removed from the server. To stop something similar from happening to your own company, always set a company password and only share it with those you trust!

In the end, the method that's most likely to produce results without annoying others is simply to talk to them and ask them to remove the offending tiles.

---

Things are slightly different however in a singleplayer game. The only legitimate way to remove a competitor's tiles is to purchase all of the company's shares, or have them go bankrupt. Depending on which AI you're using, they may also remove tiles themselves.

If you're willing to cheat however, you can open the Cheat menu (Control + Alt + C) and use the "Playing as company" option to switch to the competitor whose tiles you wish to remove. Once you're done, use the same cheat option to switch back to your own company. Note however that, as noted in Cheat menu, the game will permanently remember that you've cheated and will keep the tick mark next to any cheat options you've used - even if you restore them back to default.

Comment: The question says "human competitor in multiplayer mode", so most of the answer isn't entirely relevant.

Comment: I completely missed that part of the question, i'll update my answer to better reflect the question. Thanks for pointing that out.